# WPF/Winforms application as a service for multiple Windows User Logins

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-services

We have a WPF interactive desktop application running as a single instance application. This application is a monitoring application with certain statistics displayed in the UI based on a specific set of configuration.

As this is used by different users across different shift timings, who have their own Windows Login, the client wants a way by which once one user `LOGS-OFF`, and next user `LOGS-IN` or when a `SWITCH-USER` happens, the user who is currently using the machine should get access to the running instance of the application. For e.g., if `User1` has started the app, and `User2` logs in, the `User2` should see what `User1` was seeing and continue.

In a way, the client wants a single instance of a running application to be shared across multiple users logged in to the Windows.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not a programming question by the way, and will most likely get closed. But you can probably do it by adding the app on startup and saving the applications last state somewhere on the computer(a folder which all the users has access to) and loading that.

Comment: This is already being done, but what we want to do is share the same instance of application across multiple user logins. One thing we thought about is running it as a service, but even that way, the WPF application has to be run per user, and we were not able to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can map N logical users to the same session.
You can create a single windows user, however there will be N authentication methods.
It can be N different smartcards assigned to the same "logical" user. In the application you can detect who is the actual user by inspecting the certificate